# What is the benefit of manually specifying the MIME type when sending an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The jQuery library has a built in function called `.overrideMimeType()`. Why is this a beneficial thing to do? What kind of issues may arise if I don't do this? It seems to crop up quite frequently, but I can't find a good explanation via Google.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It hacks around web services which lie about what sort of content they are serving.

Most commonly, this involves PHP scripts since PHP defaults to claiming `Content-Type: text/html` and many PHP authors don't know they should `header("Content-Type: application/json");` before they `echo json_encode($some_data);`.